# how to prevent vs code to don't access all my files

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to prevent vs code to don't access all my files?

[image]

Comment: please add more information to your question. what do you want to achieve, what have you tried. a single image is not enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place where `index.html` is saved at is a folder that has many files inside. Please make another folder and put `index.html` inside, then go to `File -> Open Folder` and select the folder you just created. Now close the previous window and keep this new one.